# How to make a cone UV projection?

Tags: texturing, uv

I can't figure out how to make a UV Projection with a Cone. I tried Sphere, Cube and Cylinder projection too. Can somebody help?

Comment: What do you mean by a cone projection?  Do you mean how to unwrap a cone?

Comment: If the bottom Ngon of cone isn't important for texturing you can enter Top VIew and use *Project From View* from Unwrap menu.

Answer (score 5):

In "Edit Mode" select The bottom vertices and one edge and mark them as a seam by pressing CTRL + "E" and selecting mark seam from the drop down menu. Then in the UV Editor while in "Edit Mode" select all of the vertices
and unwrap them by pressing "U" and selecting Unwrap from the drop down menu.

[image]

[image]